# Can't run launch in VSCode with preLaunchTask. Always opens 'Select a task to configure' after remember choice

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I had a task not working. This task was being used as preLaunchTask in a launch configuration, it wasn't essential, so every time I ran the launch VSCode would prompt for which action to take.

After a while I clicked the "Remember this option" check on the prompt and selected "Configure Task" option.

Now even though the task is properly configured when I launch I'm always presented the "remembered" option...even without it failing.

I can't find any setting on VSCode that would eliminate that option.

The task works fine.
The launch without the preLaunchTask works fine.

launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Debug Client App",
            "type": "autohotkey",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${cwd}/Dynokey.ahk",
            "preLaunchTask": {
                "task": "IEDebugger"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "IEDebugger",
            "command": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\F12\\IEChooser.exe",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

every time I run the launch with preLaunchTask
[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
          "preLaunchTask": {
                "task": "IEDebugger"
            }
```

should become this:

```
          "preLaunchTask": "IEDebugger"
```

This is the reason why it wouldn't run.

It still does not answer where can one reset the prompt choice.